# SQL query with Group By and Having Clause in LINQ structure

Tags: linq, count, entity-framework-6, having

how do I write this query in LINQ (c# EF6)?

Can someone please help me here - I am new to Entity Framework Structure - So bit hard for me to use different clauses

```
SELECT 
    sum(remainingamount) TotalSiteCreditAmount,
    max(expirationutcdatetime) MaxExpiryDate
FROM 
    WholesaleCredits
WHERE 
    ExpirationUTCDateTime > Getdate()
GROUP BY 
    registeredcustomerid,
    siteid
HAVING 
    registeredcustomerid = :registeredCustomerId
    AND siteid = :siteId
```

Tried below thing as of now :

```
var data =  context.WholesaleCredit
                .Where(x => x.ExpirationUTCDateTime > DateTime.Now)
                .GroupBy (x => x.RegisteredCustomerId)
```

Entity Used in code:

```
 public partial class WholesaleCredits
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal CreditAmount { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal RemainingAmount { get; set; }
        public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime GeneratedUTCDateTime { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime ExpirationUTCDateTime { get; set; }
        public virtual int RegisteredCustomerId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to make a start yet? We have no clue what your entities look like.

Comment: @DavidG - Tried below few things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need HAVING here and Grouping should be provided by constant, because you have filter on grouping keys:

```cs
var data = context.WholesaleCredit
    .Where(x => x.ExpirationUTCDateTime > DateTime.Now && x.RegisteredCustomerId == registeredCustomerId && x.Site.Id == siteid)
    .GroupBy(x => 1)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        TotalSiteCreditAmount = g.Sum(x => x.RemainingAmount),
        MaxExpiryDate = g.Max(x => x.ExpirationUTCDateTime)
    })
    .First();
```